# How to query the documents that contain field from given key in array of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My original code

```
const users = ["019e1c71","19e1c72a", "1b215900"];
```

I simply get the results by

```
User.find({
  _id: {$in: users}
});
```

If I change a variable `users` to

```
const users = [{_id: "019e1c71"}, {_id: "19e1c72a"}, {_id: "1b215900"}];
```

How to get the results that contain given _id in array of the object?

Comment: You can perform the [.find array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Example: `users.find(id => id === "019e1c71");` or if it's an array of objects object: `users.find(userObj => userObj._id === "019e1c71");`

Comment: @JacobPenney that's right, but I asked for MongoDB and I'm looking for a method that built-in MongoDB or effective way to solve this problem. A method that I can use is `array.map` and change the array of objects to pure string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$or` operator takes an array of documents, which is exactly what you have.

```
const users = [{_id: "019e1c71"}, {_id: "19e1c72a"}, {_id: "1b215900"}];
User.find({$or: users});
```

Comment: Thank you! I misunderstood about operation `$or` for a long time. It's a really simple way to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know it's always `_id`:

```js
const users = [{_id: "019e1c71"}, {_id: "19e1c72a"}, {_id: "1b215900"}];

let query = { _id: { $in: users.map(x => x._id) } };
console.log(query);
```

or assuming that the keys might be different:

```js
    const users = [{_id: "019e1c71"}, {_id2: "19e1c72a"}, {_id3: "1b215900"}];

    let query = { $or: users }
    console.log(query);
```

Comment: I have a question If the keys are fixed to `_id` which the method is better?

Comment: I would prefer `$in` then the query is simpler

Answer (score 0):

You could use `findOne()` to look for the requested id, for example:

`User.findOne({_id: '019e1c71'})`

[docs.mongodb.com - findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)